# Filter values if even one raw contains any value from another table

Tags: sql, hive

I have table1

```
c1    c2
1   a
1   b
1   c
2   a
3   b
```

and table2

```
c3
a
h
y
```

I need to filter  all `c1` if even 1 one of `c2` contains any of`c3` from table2

result should be

```
c1
3
```

So far I tried

```
with cte as(
select c1, collect_set(c2) as c2
from table1
)
```

but I can't join it with table2 in such a way that will allow me to filter raws I don't need. For example, with

```
select c1
from cte 
cross join table2
```

I could filter raws like

```
1 (a, b, c) a
```

but not

```
1 (a, b, c) x
```

and in the ennd I would even get

```
2 (a) x
```

which I don't need at all.

I also thought about concatinating

```
select c1, concat_ws(',', c2)
```

and using `like '%c3%'`, but `c3` is a column with many values and not some string.

`NOT EXISTS` wouldn't work either

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select t1.c1
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.c2 = t2.c3
group by t1.c1
having count(t2.c3) = 0;
```

Comment: Wow! This query improved a query i'm using by 1000%. Thank you for sharing your knowledge!!

Answer (score -1):

Please check out Gordon's answer for a more appropriate and better solution.

```
SELECT  [c1]
FROM    @table1
WHERE   [c1] NOT IN ( SELECT    [c1]
                      FROM      @table1
                                INNER JOIN @table2 ON c2 = c3 );
```

Comment: I can't fathom why the OP would accept this answer.  It is (1) not in Hive syntax; (2) does not correctly answer the question; and (3) doesn't even efficiently implement the logic that it does implement.